# What's the cause of a very quiet top E string on my '97 MIM Strat?

Tags: strings

I recently got a 97 min strat,and the high e string is really quiet compared to the rest of my strings.Is there something I'm missing?Thanks.

Comment: which country is min? Try checking the nut height, if any frets are lifted, and if the bridge saddles are ok.

Comment: Min = MIM = made in Mexico?

Comment: please rephrase the question title so that it is clear what the question is actually about

Answer (score -1):

Particularly if it's quiet on all the pups, there's a possibility the top string has been changed for one that belongs on an acoustic guitar. Worth changing the set anyway.

Comment: Are plain acoustic strings any different from electric strings, aside from gauge? Just a steel wire in both cases, right?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - not sure, but I've tried, a long time ago, using an acoustic string on an electric guitar ( I had no other spares!) and it wasn't good. They're not always steel, though.